# Unit test for update method in C# using Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write a unit test for My Processor class I have two problems

- I do not know how to test my Methods Only.
  this is my processor

**OrderProcessor class**

```
 public  class OrderProcessor
        { 
     public   void Process(CustomersOrder order)
            {
               var oldOrder = _repository.GetOldorderId(order.Code.Value);
                if (oldOrder != 0)
                {
                    updateOrder(order);
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveOrder(order);
}
    }
private  void updateOrder(CustomersOrder order)
            {

                _repository.UpdateOrder(order);

            }

            private  void SaveOrder(CustomersOrder order)
            {
                _repository.SaveOrder(order);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Repository class**

```
  public  class Repository : IRepository
        {
            private static PracticeEntities4 _context;

            public Repository(PracticeEntities4 context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public int GetOldCustomerId( int customerCode)
            {
                var CuID= _context.Customers.First(e => e.Code == customerCode);
                return CuID.Id;
            }



            public int GetOldorderId(int orderCode)
            {
                var oldOrder = _context.CustomersOrders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == orderCode);

                return oldOrder.Id;
            }

            public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
            {
                _context.Customers.Add(customer);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            public void SaveOrder(CustomersOrder order)
            {
                _context.CustomersOrders.Add(order);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            public void UpdateOrder(CustomersOrder order)
            {

                _context.CustomersOrders.AddOrUpdate(order);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }


        }
```

and this is My unit test I don't know how to fix it and where is the problem exactly and also I want to test the Methods too.

**UnitTests Class**

```
    [TestClass]
       public class OrderProcessorTest
        {
          [ClassInitialize]   
            {...}
            [TestInitialize]
            public void TestInitialize()
            {
             ....
            }
            [TestMethod]
            public void Customer_OrderProcess()
            {
                //Arange
              Mock<IRepository> mock= new Mock<IRepository>();

                //Act
                mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldCustomerId(1001)).Returns(3);
                mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldStoreId(200)).Returns(3);       
                var dtos = OrderDeserializer.Deserialize(path);
                var dto = dtos.First(e => e.Code == 300);
                OrderBuilder builder = new OrderBuilder(mock.Object);
                builder.OrderBuild(dto);
                //Asset
                Assert.AreEqual(0, _orders.Count);
}
}
```

**Order Builder Class**

```
public class OrderBuilder
    {
        public IRepository _repository { get; set; }

        public OrderBuilder(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public CustomersOrder OrderBuild(OrderDto dto)
        {     
            var oldStoreId = _repository.GetOldStoreId(dto.StoreCode);
            var oldCustomerId = _repository.GetOldCustomerId(dto.CustomerCode);
            return new CustomersOrder()
            {
                OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.OrderDate),
                OrderStatus = dto.OrderStatus,
                DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.DeliveryDate),
                CustomerId = oldCustomerId,
                StoreId = oldStoreId,
                Code = dto.Code
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nazaning, Its usually hard for people to review large code, I would suggest to reduce your question to an extend where it can be easily replicated.

Comment: thank you I did what you said hope this is better now.

Comment: @Nazanin The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It would be awesome if you could reformat the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your code I see that there are all sorts of Mocking and Initial test setups that is taking place without a clear intention on what to test.*

#### ***Unit Test: What ?***

*Tests a unit of an application without its **external dependencies***

#### ***Unit Test: Why ?***

*Makes refactoring faster and ensures you don't break existing portion of your code*

#### ***Unit Test: Steps ?***

- We first need to re-factor the code before we do unit tests. Modularity is the key
- By using Interfaces remove the tight couplings in the code
- Inject the dependency via method parameters, constructor, properties or use Dependency Injection
- Consider using Mock objects, as a good practice, only when dealing with external    dependency.
- In the `[TestMethod]` we organize the tests into 3 categories **Arrange -> Act -> Assert**

  Example:

  ```
  //Arrange 
  var res = new Reservation();

  //Act
  var op = res.Method(new User{IsAdmin=true});

  // Assert
  Assert.IsTrue(op);
  ```

#### ***Naming Conventions in UnitTests:***

**TestProjectName:**         **`[InserProjectName].UnitTests`

  TestClasses:**                 **`[InsertClassName]Tests`**
  **TestMethod:**                  **`[MethodYourTesting]_[Scenario]_[ExpectedBehavior]`**

> **I have created a `Console` app as close as possible to your problem
>    (minus the DBContext) that you can replicate on your PC to understand
>    the various portions.**
>   **All the domain classes are part of one single**
>   **file for the sake of testability to reproduce faster.**

**Console App Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOrderProcessor
{

    public class CustomersOrder
    {
        public OrderDto Order { get; set; }
        public  List<CustomersOrder> CustomersOrders = new List<CustomersOrder>();
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public int ID { get;  set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public OrderDto Order { get; set; }
        public  List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
    public class OrderDto
    {
        public DateTime OrderDate   { get; set; }

        public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        int GetOldCustomerId(int customerCode);
        int GetOldOrderId(int orderCode);
        void SaveCustomer(Customer customer);
        void SaveOrder(CustomersOrder order);
    }


    public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private readonly Customer _cust;
        private readonly CustomersOrder _custOrder;

        public Repository(Customer cust, CustomersOrder custOrder )
        {
            _cust = cust;
            _custOrder = custOrder;
        }

        public int GetOldCustomerId(int customerCode)
        {

            var cuId = _cust.Customers.First(e => e.Code == customerCode);
            return cuId.ID;
        }

        public int GetOldOrderId(int orderCode)
        {
            var oId = _custOrder.CustomersOrders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == orderCode);
            return oId.ID;
        }

        public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
        {

            _cust.Customers.Add(customer);

        }

        public void SaveOrder(CustomersOrder order)
        {
            _custOrder.CustomersOrders.Add(order);
        }
    }

    public class OrderProcess
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public OrderProcess(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public void Process(CustomersOrder order)
        {
            var oldOrder = _repository.GetOldOrderId(order.Code);
            if (oldOrder == 0)
                _repository.SaveOrder(order);
        }
    }

    public class OrderBuilder
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public OrderBuilder(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public CustomersOrder OrderBuild(OrderDto dto)
        {

            var oldCustomerId = _repository.GetOldCustomerId(dto.CustomerCode);
            return new CustomersOrder()
            {
                Order = dto,
                OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.OrderDate),
                OrderStatus = dto.OrderStatus,
                ID = oldCustomerId,
                CustomerID = oldCustomerId,

                Code = dto.Code
            };
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cust = new Customer();
            var custOrder = new CustomersOrder();

            #region PopulatingCustomer
            //Populating OrderDto
            var dto1 = new OrderDto { Code = 1, CustomerCode = 1, OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date, OrderStatus = "OK" };
            //Populating Customer
            var customerList = cust.Customers = new List<Customer>();
            var customerOrderList = custOrder.CustomersOrders = new List<CustomersOrder>();

            var customer1 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 1,
                ID = 1, Order=dto1
            };
            var customer2 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 2,
                ID = 2,

            };

            customerList.Add(customer1);
            customerList.Add(customer2);
            #endregion

            #region PopulatingCustomerOrder

            var customersOrder1 = new CustomersOrder { Code = 1, CustomerID = 1, ID = 1, Order = dto1, OrderDate = dto1.OrderDate, OrderStatus = dto1.OrderStatus };
            customerOrderList.Add(customersOrder1);
            #endregion

            #region InvokingMethods
            //IRepository
            IRepository IRepo = new Repository(cust,custOrder);

            //OrderProcessor
            var orderProcesor = new OrderProcess(IRepo);

            //OrderBuilder
            var dto2 = new OrderDto { Code = 2, CustomerCode = 2, OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date, OrderStatus = "OK" };
            var oBuilder = new OrderBuilder(IRepo);
           var newCustOrder =  oBuilder.OrderBuild(dto2);
            customerOrderList.Add(newCustOrder);
            #endregion
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

**UnitTest Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using StackOrderProcessor;

namespace StackOrderProcessor.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RepositoryTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetOldCustomerId_WhenCalled_ReturnsOId()
        {
            //Arrange
            var cust = new Customer();
            var custOrder = new CustomersOrder();

            IRepository repo = new Repository(cust,custOrder);
            var customerList = cust.Customers = new List<Customer>();

            var dto1 = new OrderDto { Code = 1, CustomerCode = 1, OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date, OrderStatus = "OK" };
            var customer1 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 1,
                ID = 1,
                Order = dto1
            };
            var customer2 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 2,
                ID = 2,

            };

            customerList.Add(customer1);
            customerList.Add(customer2);


            //Act
            repo.GetOldCustomerId(1);


            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1); //Test will Pass as we have a customer of Code  1

        }

        [TestMethod]
        //MethodName_Scenario_Expectedbehavior
        public void SaveCustomer_WhenCalled_AddsNewCustomer()
        {

            var cust = new Customer();
            var custOrder = new CustomersOrder();

            IRepository repo = new Repository(cust, custOrder);
            var customerList = cust.Customers = new List<Customer>();

            var dto1 = new OrderDto { Code = 1, CustomerCode = 1, OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date, OrderStatus = "OK" };
            var customer1 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 1,
                ID = 1,
                Order = dto1
            };
            var customer2 = new Customer
            {
                Code = 2,
                ID = 2,

            };

            customerList.Add(customer1);
            customerList.Add(customer2);
            //Act

            var custToSave = new Customer
            {
                Code = 3,
                ID = 3,
                Order = null
            };
            repo.SaveCustomer(custToSave);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(3, customerList.Count);


        }

    }

    [TestClass]
    public class OrderProcessor1Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Process_WhenOrderIsZero_AddsNewCustomerOrder()
        {
            //Arrange
            var cust = new Customer();
            var custOrder = new CustomersOrder();
            var customerOrderList = custOrder.CustomersOrders = new List<CustomersOrder>();

            IRepository repo = new Repository(cust, custOrder);

            var orderProcessor = new OrderProcess(repo);


            var dto1 = new OrderDto { Code = 1, CustomerCode = 1, OrderDate = DateTime.Now.Date, OrderStatus = "OK" };

            var custOrder1 = new CustomersOrder { ID = 1, Code = 1, CustomerID = 1, Order = dto1, OrderDate = dto1.OrderDate, OrderStatus = dto1.OrderStatus };

            customerOrderList.Add(custOrder1);


            //Act
            orderProcessor.Process(custOrder1);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(1, customerOrderList.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: Make sure to add reference of `StackOrderProcessor` in `StackOrderProcessor.UnitTests`**

[image]

> **You will still need to better organize the Unit Test Methods, this was just for demonstration purposes, I hope concepts are much more clear now**

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough information, you don't need your repository code for this question, but OrderBuiler class and _orders field needs. I'm sorry for this comment in answers location.

Comment: - Sure, I'll try