# Unit testing fundaments question about collections and their Add, Remove, ... methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices) about best practices in unit tests, but I still don't get one thing. When I have a `List<T>` or another collection and then use `.Add` or `.Remove` method to add/remove elements, does it count as an *arrange* or an *act*?

For example, this definitely counts as *arrange*:

```cs
List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>
{
    0.01668m,
    0.01666m
};
```

Consider the following examples:

```cs
public class IndicatorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SimpleMovingAverage_MultipleCloseValues_ReturnsSMA()
    {
        // Arrange
        SimpleMovingAverage sma = new SimpleMovingAverage(5);

        // Act
        sma.Add(0.01692m);
        sma.Add(0.01685m);
        sma.Add(0.01686m);
        sma.AddRange(new List<decimal>
        {
            0.01668m,
            0.01666m
        });
        decimal actual = sma.GetResult();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(0.016794m, actual);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SimpleMovingAverageBuilder_MultipleCloseValues_ReturnsSMA()
    {
        // Arrange
        SimpleMovingAverage sma = new SimpleMovingAverageBuilder(5)
            .Add(0.01692m)
            .Add(0.01685m)
            .Add(0.01686m)
            .Add(0.01668m)
            .Add(0.01666m)
            .Build();

        // Act
        decimal actual = sma.GetResult();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(0.016794m, actual);
    }
}
```

I believe the second test is okay convention-wise. What about the first one?

Should I do it like that:

```cs
[Fact]
public void SimpleMovingAverage_MultipleCloseValues_ReturnsSMA()
{
    // Arrange
    SimpleMovingAverage sma = new SimpleMovingAverage(5);
    List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>
    {
        0.01668m,
        0.01666m
    };

    // Act
    sma.Add(0.01692m);
    sma.Add(0.01685m);
    sma.Add(0.01686m);
    sma.AddRange(values);
    decimal actual = sma.GetResult();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(0.016794m, actual);
}
```

Or so:

```cs
[Fact]
public void SimpleMovingAverage_MultipleCloseValues_ReturnsSMA()
{
    // Arrange
    SimpleMovingAverage sma = new SimpleMovingAverage(5);
    List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>
    {
        0.01668m,
        0.01666m
    };

    sma.Add(0.01692m);
    sma.Add(0.01685m);
    sma.Add(0.01686m);
    sma.AddRange(values);

    // Act
    decimal actual = sma.GetResult();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(0.016794m, actual);
}
```

Which one is better? Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: I've outlined the best practices, including AAA(Arrange Act Asset) in this answer here : [IntroUnitTests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029608/4686729),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `act` section should contain the action that your test is targeting. In your case that is the call of `GetResult()`.

The `arrange` section therefore contains everything that lead to the action you are about to test. In your case that's setting up your `SimpleMovingAverage` instance.

I'd suggest to go with your last version:

```cs
[Fact]
public void SimpleMovingAverage_MultipleCloseValues_ReturnsSMA()
{
    // Arrange
    SimpleMovingAverage sma = new SimpleMovingAverage(5);
    List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>
    {
        0.01668m,
        0.01666m
    };

    sma.Add(0.01692m);
    sma.Add(0.01685m);
    sma.Add(0.01686m);
    sma.AddRange(values);

    // Act
    decimal actual = sma.GetResult();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(0.016794m, actual);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought the same, just needed a confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

Both of last 2 facts are same and i think u know the answer this question too. Believe yourself.